# How can I lock portions of a Mac MS Word document?

Tags: mac

I'm creating a letterhead template for our company. I want to lock (make uneditable) the header and footer of the letterhead which contains our logo and company contact information but still allow others to change the content in the body of the letterhead for their own use. I'm working in MS Word for the Mac 2011.